# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run react native cli and I'm coming across the error below:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I was getting different build errors yesterday and when trying to debug I set the JAVA_HOME to their answer on SO. Since, I have been getting the error above and found no solution. Most of the answers consist of removing \bin but as you can see that is not set in the current directory.

I have tried reinstalling Java and setting it to the known path but the error did not change.

Is it strange that I had no Java file prior to manual installation this morning and the cli was running?

Grateful for any advice and help.

Comment: is that the correct path to your jdk installation ?

Comment: Is it strange that CLI was working before? No. There was a Java Runtime installed before. In Windows, this was probably pointed to by this path `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux

Comment: @hfontanez are you suggesting I point JAVA_HOME to the path you have specified above?

Comment: @jhamon - it's not pointing to anything at this current moment. Can you give me some steps. I'm very new to this all

Comment: given information is not helpful, mostly confusing. Please add to question: 1) WHERE you installed JAVA; 2) the content of `JAVA_HOME` (e.g. `echo %JAVA_HOME%`); 3) the content of `PATH`; 4) result of `dir "%JAVA_HOME%"

Comment: @JamesOwen I am not suggesting that. I was merely pointing out potential reasons why you are getting this behavior. I suggest you do what user16320675 suggested above.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was because I renamed inside bin the executables "java" and "javaw" to other names, I rolled back that change and now it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, you are misconfigured.
it's my pc JAVA_HOME.
[image]

[image]